# Allow PHP date() function to recognise dd-mm-yy format

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm looking to slightly modify the PHP `date()` function so that it recognises the UK 6 digit format of dd/mm/yy or dd-mm-yy. Understandably, it will think that a date which is in this form is instead in international (yy-mm-dd) format.

I still wish to pass it into the date function as this will allow it to recognise other formats, but as I'm based in the UK people are most likely going to put it in the UK format.

Any ideas? I suspect Regex is involved in the solution to this problem...

### Update - my solution

Using parts from the answer below, this was how I was able to change it just in the case of dd/mm/yy:

```
$s_date = str_replace('/', '-', $s_date);

preg_match('^(.*)[-](.*)[-](.*)$^', $s_date, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    if (strlen($matches[3]) == 2) {
        $matches[3] = '20'.$matches[3];
    }
    $s_date = $matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3];
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to actually modify the date() function (which requires changes to PHP core) or simply to write a function that converts dd/mm/yy or dd-mm-yy to yy-mm-dd?

Comment: Sorry yes, to clarify I'm not really looking to modify the core, just really the variable returned when it is in this format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function will allow you to check for dd-mm-yy and dd/mm/yy.

By using a str replace - you force the date to always be in the 'dd-mm-yy' format. strtotime interprets dates with a "-" as the format you want.

```
// Is this a valid date?
    function valid_date($str) 
    {
        $str = str_replace('/', '-', $str);
        if ($arr = strtotime($str))
        {
            $arr = explode("-", date("d-m-Y", strtotime($str)));
            $yyyy = $arr[2];
            $mm = $arr[1];
            $dd = $arr[0];
            if (is_numeric($yyyy) && is_numeric($mm) && is_numeric($dd))
            {
                return checkdate($mm, $dd, $yyyy);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

[Quote from strtotime:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still interpreting `dd-mm-yy` as `yy-mm-dd`. Any ideas how to stop this interpretation, whilst still allowing `date()` to understand a string like `2 November 2013`?

Answer (score 2):

Asking about the `date()` function is barking up the wrong tree.

The `date()` function **outputs** a date string, not input. The input for `date()` is an integer timestamp value. You can't get `date()` to recognise any kind of string input.

If you're dealing with date fields input as strings, the `date()` function is not the one you want to use; PHP provides different functions for that.

There are a number of options, but the best one would be to use [the `DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), and more specifically, the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

This tells the program to import the date string, and process it in the format you expect. This removes any possible ambiguity from the input (ie the program knows that the input is dd-mm-yy rather than having to guess which way round the dd, mm and yy parts are):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', '09-04-12');
```

Once you've done that, then you can use the `$date` object created in the line above to work with the date in your code, and output it in any format you like. eg:

```
echo $date->format('j-M-Y');   //prints 9-Apr-2012
```

Hope that helps.